# After removing stopwords, my output is not saved when I futher clean up my tweets in R

Tags: r, output, tm, stop-words

I am doing sentiment analysis, I have two documents in my directory of 
corpus 1 is of positive tweets and other is of negative tweets but in 
comparison wordcloud I have words those are stopwords. This means it is not 
removing the stopwords ("english").
I created custom stopwords but failed to retain that output too. After that I have searched and found a stopwords.txt file of stopwords that I have downloaded from the github and used it to remove the stopwords. For this I have to convert the corpus (atomic vector) to table and then to vector (dataframe) as to read this file. I have combined it with stopwords of `tm` library.
The output was as expected, but when I tried to remove the punctuation and inspected the corpus, the output was just according to removePunctuation output not retaining the output of stopwords.
Then, I tried the removeNumbers and inspect the corpus but it is not retaining the output of stopwords but retaining the output of removePunctuation. 
so, what is the problem here?

What I am missing here?
[This is the code]
[1][This is the output after removing the stopwords from the tweets using R]
[2][This is the output after appling other cleaning like removePunctuation, 
removeNumbers, stipwhitespace, stemDocument but it is not retaining the removed stopwords output]
[3]
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMbvD.png
    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/18H3P.png
    [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxaJE.png

This is the code that I have used. I have put the two text files in the 
directory and converted it into the corpus.

```
library(tm)
tweets_corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = "D:/New-RStudio-
Project/tweets"))
summary(tweets_corpus)
##cleaning the tweets_corpus ##
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, tolower)
##removing stopwords##
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, removeWords, 
stopwords("english"))
inspect(clean_tweets_corpus)
##having stopwords.txt (collection of stopwords) to remove the stopwords##
stop = read.table("stopwords.txt", header = TRUE)
class(stop)
stop
stop_vec = as.vector(stop$CUSTOM_STOP_WORDS)
class(stop_vec)
stop_vec
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, removeWords, 
c(stopwords("english"), stop_vec))
inspect(clean_tweets_corpus)
## remove to have single characters ##
remove_multiplechar<-function(x) gsub("\\b[A-z]\\b{1}"," ",x)
clean_tweets_corpus<-tm_map(tweets_corpus, 
content_transformer(remove_multiplechar))
inspect(clean_tweets_corpus)
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, removePunctuation)
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus,removeNumbers)
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, stripWhitespace)
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, stemDocument)
inspect(clean_tweets_corpus)
str(clean_tweets_corpus)
```

Comment: Your function calls are incorrect.  `clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, ...)` you are calling the `tm_map` function with tweets_corpus but saving the results to clean_tweets_corpus.  Then next call to `tm_map` you are still using the original unmodified tweets_corpus and overwriting the updated clean_tweet_corpus.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Dave2e.  what can I do. kindly correct the code please. as I am new to R so cant understand much of this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the corrected code, replacing "tweets_corpus" with "clean_tweets_corpus" in all calls to `tm_map` except the first one:

```
library(tm)
tweets_corpus <- Corpus(DirSource(directory = "D:/New-RStudio-Project/tweets"))
summary(tweets_corpus)

##cleaning the tweets_corpus ##
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(tweets_corpus, tolower)

##removing stopwords##
##having stopwords.txt (collection of stopwords) to remove the stopwords##
stop = read.table("stopwords.txt", header = TRUE)
stop_vec = as.vector(stop$CUSTOM_STOP_WORDS)

clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(clean_tweets_corpus, removeWords, 
                              c(stopwords("english"), stop_vec))

## remove to have single characters ##
remove_multiplechar<-function(x) gsub("\\b[A-z]\\b{1}"," ",x)
clean_tweets_corpus<-tm_map(clean_tweets_corpus, 
                            content_transformer(remove_multiplechar))

clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(clean_tweets_corpus, removePunctuation)
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(clean_tweets_corpus, removeNumbers)
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(clean_tweets_corpus, stripWhitespace)
clean_tweets_corpus <- tm_map(clean_tweets_corpus, stemDocument)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!  @Dave2e It has really solved my problem. Thanks again :)